# C# DateTime Conversion between UTC to Local TimeZone

Tags: datetime

1. Able to Convert date time local to UTC using below codes.


   `a. TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTimeValue, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localTimeZone));` 


   `b. TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeValue, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localTimeZone), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");`
2. And used below codes to convert UTC to Local.

   `a. TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTimeValue, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localTimeZone));`


   `b. TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTimeValue, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC"), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localTimeZone));`

It is working fine, when the application run in visual studio(debug mode). But after host the application in US Server(Eastern TimeZone) and browse application from India, the time conversion from UTC to local is not working. 
Here localTimeZone is "Indian Standard Time"(local time zone get from client machine and send to server from Date time conversion.)

**Example:**
**IST DateTime:** 12/10/2018 18:37 
**UTC DateTime:** 2018-12-10 06:05 (IST to UTC) 
**Converted DateTime:** 12/11/2018 05:07 (UTC to IST)

If we set the local time zone to "Eastern Time zone", conversion doing correctly.

Can any one provide solution for this scenario.

Comment: The clock on web servers should be set to use UTC, even if they are in the USA. Can you find out what timezone the web server is set to?

Comment: Or just [ask the server for the UTC time](http://www.creativedeletion.com/2015/08/07/why-not-to-use-server-local-time.html) with [DateTime.UtcNow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=netframework-4.7.2) and work from that.

Comment: Thanks Andrew Morton. It was very help full to know how the code doing conversion in server. The code is working fine in server as well. The only problem is i was returning the results  as json result to view then parse and formatted(moment(dateTimeValue).format('L HH:mm')) the Datetime. This might be issue with json Serialization or moment plugin for different time zones.
Finally resolved the issue by formatting the Datetime in C# and return as string to view.